# Determining if 2 vector fields are proportional: using flux

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Consider 2 vector fields $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{G}$. If the closed surface integrals

$$
\oint_S \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S} = A \tag{1}
$$

$$\oint_S \vec{G} \cdot d\vec{S} = B \tag{2}
$$

for any surface $S$, can we conclude $\vec{F} \propto \vec{G}$? This would definitely make the above integrals a true statement. But given equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ alone, I don't think the proportionality necessarily follows. It would be the easiest conclusion to make, but it might not be the only conclusion. I'm tempted to say "yes, they are proportional", only because the statement holds true for *every* closed surface. If the statement were true only for a single closed surface, there's no way you can conclude that they are proportional. Then again, I'm still hesitant to conclude proportionality because I am aware of the following: if the closed line integral of two vector fields are $0$ for every closed loop, this just means that they are conservative. And I know of 2 vector fields (springs and inverse-square) which are conservative but aren't proportional.

For "physics reasons" I would really like $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{G}$ to be proportional. Are $(1)$ and $(2)$ sufficient to make this conclusion? If I also know that $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{G}$ are parallel, do I now have enough to conclude proportionality? This is not true of my problem at hand, but if $\nabla \times \vec{F} = 0$ and $\nabla \times \vec{G} = 0$, is this enough to conclude that the fields are proportional? Thanks in advance. I'm hoping the addition of the parallel requirement is enough to guarantee proportionality

Comment: Note that since $\oint_S (\nabla\times\vec A)\cdot \hat n \,dS=0$, for any vector $\vec A$ sufficiently smooth, then $\oint_S (\vec F+\nabla \times \vec A)\cdot \hat n\,dS=A$ also.  If  $\nabla \times \vec F=\nabla \times \vec G=0$ we can choose $\vec A$ such that $\nabla\times\nabla\times \vec A=0$.  Is $\vec F$ guaranteed to be parallel to $\vec F+\nabla \times \vec A$?

Comment: I didn't quite follow your second sentence. Did you take the curl of both sides of the last part of your 1st sentence? Then place the curl in the integrand and distribute it? I do know that in my question $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{G}$ are parallel (just edited) @MarkViola

Comment: You're question is "Are $\vec F$ and $\vec G$ parallel."  Suppose $\vec G=\vec F+\nabla \times \vec A$, where $\nabla\times\nabla\times \vec A=0$.  So, if $\nabla \times\vec F=0$, then $\nabla \times\vec G=0$ and if $\oint_S \vec F \cdot \hat n\,dS=A$, then $\oint_S \vec G \cdot \hat n\,dS=A$ also.  Does this mean that $\vec F$ is parallel to $\vec G=\vec F+\nabla \times \vec A$?

Comment: @MarkViola I see your argument. You're saying $\vec{G}$ could take the form $\vec{G} = (B/A) \vec{F} + \nabla \times \vec{A}$ and still satisfy my equations $(1)$ and $(2)$. There's no reason for the field $\nabla \times \vec{A}$ to point in the same direction as $\vec{F}$ and therefore $\vec{G}$ isn't guaranteed be proportional to $\vec{F}$ because they aren't even parallel. However if I now stipulate that the fields are parallel $\vec{G} = f(x,y,z)\vec{F}$, is there an easy was to see that $f$ has to be the constant function $B/A$?

Comment: @DWade64 It's not usual to talk about proportional vector fields. Do you mean parallel? The flux of any constant field over a closed surface is zero (divergence theorem). However, two constant fields need not be parallel.

Comment: @OliverJones Oh yes I should have been more precise. By proportional, I meant both parallel and differing by only a constant. $\vec{G} = \alpha \vec{F}$ where $\alpha$ is a constant

Comment: @DWade64 Well, as I explained in my comment, this can't happen.Take $\vec{F}=\vec{i}$ and $\vec{G}=\vec{j}$.

Comment: @DWade64 By the way, it's possible to show that if the flux of $\vec{F}$ over all closed surfaces is constant, then $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{F}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If the flux of $\vec{F}$ over all closed surfaces is constant, then it can be shown that $\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{F}=0$. Hence $\vec{F}$ is constant.

Comment: How did you go about proving this if I may ask? Inverse square fields $\hat{r}/r^2$ also have constant flux ($4\pi$) for any surface around the origin, $0$ for any enclosed surface not containing the origin. However, I'm interested in the proof of the divergence statement that you give. Inverse square fields also have zero divergence (everywhere except the origin where it's undefined)

Comment: @DWade64 You need to be careful with inverse square fields because they have a singularity at the origin. For a proof of my claim, you can use the following description of divergence: $\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{F}(P_0)=\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{V(B_a)}\iint_{S_a}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{S}$.Here, $B_a$ is a ball centered at $P_0$ and $S_a$ is its boundary surface.